# How to know the roundtrip time of each clients from the server?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, meteor, network-programming

I am doing a real-time application where it matter to the server to know exactly what time did the client do an action in order to do latency compensation on the server side.

For example if a client asks for a particular resource on the server (e.g, the exact time), and the server know that this request took 1 second to go from the client to server, then the server can send a response to the client with a 1 second compensation to the client.

Anyone know how I can get the trip time from `Meteor.method` call ? Or what other technique I can use to achieve the above ?
Thank you

Comment: without rading all ur question ... send timestamp using ajax

Comment: It will never be completely secure though since the user could fake a time on the client

Answer (score 0):

I found this: [mizzao:time-sync](https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-timesync), looking in the code I see that it calculates round trip. Maybe it's a starting point.

Comment: This calculate the ping and gives it to the client, not the server. Of course each client could send to the server it's own ping to the server, but it would be to easy to send a fake ping value.